# How to display validation errors on WooCommerce user registration before default errors

Tags: wordpress, validation, woocommerce

I'm using the following filter & action to produce some custom validation errors on woocommerce registration process.

filter

```
woocommerce_registration_errors
```

action

```
woocommerce_register_post
```

The problem is that both of the hooks above, are fired after some basic validations of woocommerce such as checking email, and password.

I want to limit some IP's to not register, and the error should be at the top of validation errors. So first we check if the ip is valid, now we can go further and do other validations.

I couldn't find any other action or filter.

Comment: i dont know about woocomerce validation by ip address, but yet another way is why dont you simply restrict user by ip address defining in htaccess or using plugin [Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/screenshots/)

Comment: @Noman, My question is not about ip restriction. it was an example. Actually I want to show a validation error with highest priority before woocommerce default validations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After exploring the source code more, I realized that there is another filter which executed sooner before `wc_create_new_customer` function.

here's the filter hook

```
woocommerce_process_registration_errors
```

You can add those errors you want to display before username, email, and password check using this filter

```
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_process_registration_errors', array( $this, 'process_registration_errors' ) );

        public function process_registration_errors( $errors ) {

           if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
                $errors->add( 'first_name_error',
                __( 'First name is required!', 'xxx' ) );
           }
        }
```